# PostgreSQL renaming table sequences and primary key

Tags: postgresql

Is it necessary or important to rename table sequences and primary keys when we rename a table in PostgreSQL? Does it affect something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically your database will keep working as always without the rename so I would say it depends. If your primary key has a generic name like `id` obviously it is still valid regardless of the new table name. If the name is in the form `old_table_name_id` or something like that then you have semantic inconsistency. In larger projects this can be confusing **for humans**. Good names are important just like they are in code so I would rename in this case. Same goes for sequences.

Answer (score 1):

No, unless you want to keep the names in sync to avoid confusing people.

The identity of an object is its Oid.